# Add a list to a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have a df

```
     col1     col2
0     1     ONE AAKLD
1     2     TWO ERBB
2     3     THE COCCNUT
3     4     WOW AACE
```

and I have the following lists

```
list1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
list2 = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
list3 = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

I want to add the list values to different columns of particular rows in the df based on condition i.e., if *col2* in df has *AA* ,the i need the *list1* to be appended to that.

Expected output:

```
     col1     col2        1    2    3
0     1     ONE AAKLD    a1    a2   a3
1     2     TWO ERBB     b1    b2   b3
2     3     THE COCCNUT  c1    c2   c3
3     4     WOW AACE     a1    a2   a3
```

Thanks

Comment: you can use pd.concat()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below provides required output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(  {'col1':[1,2,3,4,], 'col2':['AA','BB','CC','AA']})

list1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
list2 = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
list3 = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']


df = pd.DataFrame([list1, list2, list3], columns=['1','2','3'])

df['col2'] = df['1'].str.split('', expand=True)[1].str.upper()*2

pd.merge(df_1, df, left_on='col2',right_on='col2')
```

[image]

**Update as per OP's comments below**

Building upon earlier logic of **MERGE**. You can easily change **MATCHING** criteria if need arise.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
## Data Prep
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(  {'col1':[1,2,3,4,], 'col2':['ONE AAKLD','TWO ERBB','THE COCCNUT','WOW AACE']})
df_1['join_col'] = 1

list1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
list2 = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
list3 = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']

## Logic
df = pd.DataFrame([list1, list2, list3], columns=['1','2','3'])

df['match_col'] = df['1'].str.split('', expand=True)[1].str.upper()*2

df['join_col'] = 1

df_2 = pd.merge(df_1, df, left_on='join_col', right_on = 'join_col')

df_2['Is_Match'] = df_2[['col2', 'match_col']].apply(lambda x: x[1] in x[0] , axis = 1)

df_2[df_2['Is_Match'] == True][['col1','col2','1','2','3']]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have one more question. If incase the col2 values are not static just like "AA" and it may contain "AA" as part of it ex, "ONE AA TUBE". in this case how to join col2 with list1..

Comment: It certainly can be done

Comment: Please check updated code.

Answer (score 1):

another option is using `map`:

```
d = {'AA':list1,'BB':list2,'CC':list3}

df_1[[1,2,3]] = df_1['col2'].map(d).agg(pd.Series)

print(df_1)
'''
   col1 col2   1   2   3
0     1   AA  a1  a2  a3
1     2   BB  b1  b2  b3
2     3   CC  c1  c2  c3
3     4   AA  a1  a2  a3
```

**UPD**

so it's not absolutly clear what your data is, anyway you can try this (it won't work properly if you have more than one double caracters per string):

```
df_1[[1,2,3]] = df_1['col2'].str.extract(r'(([A-Z])\2)')[0].map(d).agg(pd.Series)

>>> df_1
'''
   col1         col2   1   2   3
0     1    ONE AAKLD  a1  a2  a3
1     2     TWO ERBB  b1  b2  b3
2     3  THE COCCNUT  c1  c2  c3
3     4     WOW AACE  a1  a2  a3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have one more question. If incase the col2 values are not static just like "AA" and it may contain "AA" as part of it ex, "ONE AA TUBE". in this case how to join col2 with list1..

Comment: @SM079 I'm not sure that I understand what exactly you mean, could you add a data example to your question above?

Comment: I have updated the question. If u see col2 has value "ONE AAKLD". If the value contains "AA" in it, then it should be merged to list1. Were you able to understand my question now ?

Comment: @SM079 check the UPD

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `pd.concat()` and Pandas' `Series`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3],"col2":[4,5,6]})

lst = pd.Series([7,8,9])

pd.concat((df,lst),axis=1)
```

Comment: It needs to be joined based on the condition. if Col2 has 'AA' then values from list1 should be joined to that row only